# MGRS(Military Grid Reference System) reverse geocode in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, reverse-geocoding, mgrs

How can we reverse geocode MGRS (military grid reference system) strings in ArcMap?

MGRS strings use alphanumeric notation to identify a location on the earth.

For example, I have 34TCK9320739642. How can I get the address (city, state, name, country, etc.)?

Comment: You might have to do it in 2 steps. Convert the MGRS to lat/lon, then find the address.

Comment: Close votes, really? What's hard to understand in the question?

Comment: It might help if the question gave the meaning of the Military Grid Reference System acronym in the question body.

Comment: There is a tag that someone can look up... b-> .

Comment: **I** didn't vote to close it.  The confusion might also involve what "Name" might be extracted.  Given that MGRS strings describe a rectangle, not a point, handling multiple matches needs to be considered.

Comment: ArcGIS has a tool to map Points from MGRS strings. It is available in Projections and Transformation and is named Convert Coordinate Notation.

Comment: tanks for your answer but I have lat/long I want addrsdd from mgrs